# Trying to send two stuff inside my pin to the next page, error: Cannot convert method group expression to object

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, maps

So I want to send two things in my pin when I push it to another page, the "Setbinding" works and the string (myString) gets pushed fine to the other page with the correct info. When I try to push my second string (mySecondString) through a setvalue/getvalue function i get the error: "Cannot convert method group expression to object." I have tried to use a string as well on the "Detailpage" but same error.

```
pin.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, new Binding (myString));
pin.BindingContext = myString;


pin.SetValue (Label.TextProperty, mySecondString);
pin.GetValue (Label.TextProperty);

pin.Clicked += onButtonClicked1;


void onButtonClicked1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pin pin = (Pin)sender;
        Navigation.PushAsync (new DetailPage (pin.SetValue, pin.BindingContext ));

    }


public DetailPage (object info1, object info2)
```

Updated version:

```
pin.SetValue (Label.TextProperty, mySecondString);
new DetailPage  (pin.GetValue(Label.TextProperty));
```

Answer (score 0):

`pin.SetValue` is a method, so you need to use it as one (by adding brackets).
Also, I assume what you want to use is the getter, not the setter, as SetValue propably doesn't have a return value.

Try:

```
new DetailPage(pin.GetValue(), pin.BindingContext)
```

Comment: i get an error: cannot cast source type to destination type. (the strings have a value from my database)

Comment: Can't you just use pin.Text or pin.Label? Usually there's a code property for each DependencyProperty... Because GetValue returns object of course and you still have to cast it.

Comment: I am alrdy using pin.label for another string and pin.text is not possible i think? i try to reach it but cannot seem to find it.

Comment: so to get this getvaue/setvalue code to work, i need to add a dependencyproperty if i understand correctly? so I need to put a piece of code inside pin.GetValue()? and remove the label.textproperty?

Comment: I think you are missunderstanding the concept of dependency properties. Looks like you have to inherit from Pin (create a new class) add the required properties/dependency properties there, and use that class then. Maybe read into dependency properties a little.

Comment: would be really helpful if you could give me an example of how it would look like with my code, been googling for a long time not solving this so any sort of help would be very much appreciated